# CakePHP - Carregar uma background-image css

Tags: php, css, cakephp

Não estou conseguindo carregar minha imagem no Background do Css

style.css - funcionando, apenas não conseguindo chamar essa imagem

```
.layout{
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;  
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:('../img/background.png');
}
```

o .htaccess - dentro do webroot esse

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

e o html

```
<div class="layout">
      <div class="layout-image">
          <img src="img/layout.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito q falte o comando **url** entre a propriedade **background-image** e o caminho especificado;
Exemplo: `background-image: url('../img/background.png');`

Comment: nossa um erro tão grosseiro da minha parte, muito obrigado!